Attempting to find relative data patterns
I'm working on a python based project and I need help to find the following:
* common pairs/groups of columns to contain a 1 when initial column contains a 1 
    - for the overall data
    - for each day of the week

* uncommon/unlikely pairs/groups to contain a 1 when the initial column contains a 1
    - for the overall data
    - for each day of the week

* advise on ML option for pattern recognition or forecast to find pattens in the odd/even, high/low, sum, dates, day values in the csv file and maybe the rows of 0s and 1s in the excel file.

Below you will find a description of my file structure.
CSV file
contents with headers
*Date (format: 2024-12-31)

*Day (name of the day for date)

*Picks (a string of twenty unique numbers separated by "-") 

*O/E(ODD/EVEN values)

*H/L (HIGH/LOW values)

*SUM (sum of the twenty unique numbers)

XLSX file
contains with headers
*Date(format: 2024-12-31),

*"1" to "70", 
               
    -For each of the 70 columns there is a 1 or 0 in the data to denote an 
    appearance by the number (header value) for the date on that row. 
    

    -there is only 20 columns with a 1 on any given row, 
    the other 50 contain a 0. 

    -the numbers are randomly chosen.

I have used the following code so far to get some relevant statistics for my use, but I'm stuck as to how to go about finding relation patterns within the large dataset I have (10+ years worth of daily data).
Here is the class I made to calculate and sort the data so far:

class DataProcessor:
    def __init__(self, stats_dir, combined_file, graph_file):
        self.stats_dir = stats_dir
        self.combined_file = combined_file
        self.graph_file = graph_file
        self.days_of_week = days_of_week

    def get_frequent_values(self):
        df = pd.read_excel(self.graph_file)
        df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
        column_frequencies_overall = {
            col: df[col].sum() / len(df) for col in df.columns[1:]
        }
        column_frequencies_per_day = {
            col: {
                day: data[col].sum() / len(data)
                for day, data in df.groupby(df["Date"].dt.day_name())
            }
            for col in df.columns[1:]
        }
        return column_frequencies_overall, column_frequencies_per_day

    def top_10_common_columns(self, column_num):
        column_num = f"{column_num}"
        # Read the Excel file
        df = pd.read_excel(self.graph_file)
        # Convert 'Date' column to datetime type
        df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0])
        df["Day Name"] = df["Date"].dt.day_name()

        # Dynamically specify the specified column
        specified_column = df[column_num]

        # Find the rows where the specified column is 1
        specified_column_ones = df[df[column_num] == 1]

        # Overall top 10 most common columns
        overall_top_10 = (
            specified_column_ones.select_dtypes(include=["int", "float"])
            .drop(columns=[column_num])
            .sum()
            .nlargest(10)
        )

        # For each day of the week
        day_of_week_top_10 = {}
        for day in df["Day Name"].unique():
            # Filter rows for the specific day of the week
            day_of_week_data = specified_column_ones[
                specified_column_ones["Day Name"] == day
            ]
            # Find top 10 most common columns
            top_10 = (
                day_of_week_data.select_dtypes(include=["int", "float"])
                .drop(columns=[column_num])
                .sum()
                .nlargest(10)
            )
            day_of_week_top_10[day] = top_10

        return overall_top_10, day_of_week_top_10

    def create_json_files(self):
        for num in range(1, 71):
            self.process_json_file(num)

    def process_json_file(self, num):
        overall, daily = self.get_frequent_values()
        overall_key = list(overall.keys())[int(num) - 1]
        overall_value = overall[overall_key]
        daily_key = list(daily.keys())[int(num) - 1]
        daily_value = daily[daily_key]
        hot_overall, hot_daily = self.top_10_common_columns(num)
        hot_items = {
            "Overall": hot_overall,
            "Daily": hot_daily,
        }
        created_date = datetime.now().isoformat()
        json_data = {
            "Created": created_date,
            "Overall": {overall_key: overall_value},
            "Daily": {daily_key: daily_value},
            "Hot": hot_items,
            "Cold": "soon",
        }

        json_file = os.path.join(self.stats_dir, f"{num}.json")
        if os.path.exists(json_file):
            with open(json_file, "r") as existing_json:
                existing_data = json.load(existing_json)
                existing_created_date = existing_data.get("Created")
                if (
                    existing_created_date
                    and datetime.fromisoformat(existing_created_date) >= datetime.now()
                ):
                    print(f"{num}.json up-to-date\n")
                    return
        else:
            os.makedirs(self.stats_dir, exist_ok=True)
            with open(json_file, "w") as jsonfile:
                json.dump(json_data, jsonfile, indent=4)
            print(f"{num}.json file created\n")

    def json_create_func(self):
        self.create_json_files()


Thank you for reading..

An explanation of what your data looks like is helpful, but not sufficient. At best, anyone looking to test your code and possible improvements to it is going to be forced to create a bunch of examples themselves.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So what is your question? Did you see the [tour] and [ask] yet?

Sorry. I want to create a database of the various properties of each column of data. a matrix i believe, where i can view the relation between all the columns in such a way that i can view a columns data to find:
- Hot - top columns to contain a 1 when the initial column contains a 1


- Cold - the top most unlikely or lowest probable columns to contain a 1 when the initial column contains a 1

for starters.
